# Namespace resolution in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an MVC 4 website that makes use of areas, lets call it 'MyMVC'.

As in most MVC projects there is a folder called 'Models' in the root of the website.

Inside this 'Models' directory there is a class called 'MyViewModel.cs' which contains a public class called 'MyViewModel' with a namespace of 'MyMVC.Models'.

Now, in one of the areas, call it 'Area1', there is also the typical MVC structure that also contains a directory called 'Models'. It also contains a class 'MyViewModel.cs' which also contains a class called 'MyViewModel', this time with a namespace of 'MyMVC.Areas.Area1.Models'.

Inside a view I am working on that is inside of the 'Area1\Views' directory I have at the top:

```
@model MyMVC.Areas.Area1.Models.MyViewModel
@using MyMVC.Areas.Area1.Models
```

When I go to reference the the MyViewModel like so, for example:

```
MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel();
```

I get an ambiguous error and it thinks I am referring to the other MyViewModel class although as you can see I have clearly specified with the @model directive and the @using directive which one I am referring to.

Can anyone explain what the ambiguity is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what the ambiguity is?

The ambiguity is not in your view. It's in your controller code:

```
MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel();
```

If in this controller you have both:

```
using MyMVC.Models;
using MyMVC.Areas.Area1.Models;
```

it's more than obvious that the C# compiler has no way of knowing which class you are referring to. You could remove the ambiguity by fully specifying the name of the class:

```
var mvm = new MyMVC.Areas.Area1.Models.MyViewModel();
```

---

UPDATE:

You might also have the namespace referenced in the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` file which is effectively bringing it into scope globally in all your views.

Comment: This is in the view. Also, the controller only references the second one as well although I don;t see the connection between the controller and the view in that way.

Comment: In a view? You are instantiating the view model in a view??????? WOW, you must be doing something very wrong then. Anyway, the same remark stands true for the view. You need to fully qualify the model type to avoid the possible ambiguity of the C# compiler.

Comment: I'm not literally doing that. I was just using an example. I am actually using a generic (kendo grid if you must know) and it is having the issue. =)

Comment: Fully qualifying the model type should resolve your issue. Or rename the view model.

Comment: I did fully qualify it with the @using statement. I reproduce the same thing in a console app and it doesn't have the issue. What am I missing? And I know I can solve it by using the fully qualified, I am just trying to understand why I have no mention of the other namespace yet it thinks I am referring to that other namespace.

Comment: That's because you have both namespaces in scope. Probably because they are defined in the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/wbe.config` file. It would have been absolutely the same in any C# class. If you have both namespaces in scope the compiler cannot possibly disambiguate this `MyViewModel` usage and you are going to have to either explicitly specify it or remove one of the 2 namespaces that are in scope (which of course in this case might break some other views that are relying on this namespace).

Comment: That I believe is what I am missing. Put that as your answer and I will mark it correct. If you have an msdn link too that would be great. Thanks Darin.

Comment: For whatever reason it is hard to find solid info about the namespaces section BUT I found this: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/importing-namespaces-into-razor-views-in-asp.net-mvc-3 which explains it is there to prevent the developer from having to repeat them in every single view. So now I know why: it is basically auto inserted and that was the clash.